# Subscribing or assigning one RxJS observable to another, angular Resolve Guard

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am attempting to use a resolve guard in angular to preload data for a route.

My routing module has the following code:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DiscussionListComponent,
    resolve: { discussionList$: DiscussionListResolverService }
  }
];
```

The **DiscussionListResolver** service instantiates and has the following code:

```
 resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<DiscussionList[]> | Observable<never> {
    console.log('DiscussionListResover, RouterStateSnapshot.url: ' + state.url);
    return this.discussionListService.getDiscussionList().pipe(
      // @ts-ignore
       map( discussionList => {
         console.log('DiscussionListResolverService returning discusionList:' + discussionList);
         return of(discussionList);
       }),
      catchError( err => {
        console.log('DiscussionListResolverService returning EMPTY 1');
        return EMPTY;
      })
    );
```

It produces the following output in the console

```
DiscussionListResolverService returning discusionList:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

So it seems I have the 3 objects I want, the trouble is getting them into the component.

The problem may be with the // @ts-ignore, which was giving me the following error with my pipe:

```
ERROR in src/app/discussion/discussion-list/discussion-list-resolver.service.ts:25:8 - error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 2.
```

The **DiscussionListService** looks like this:

```
export class DiscussionListService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getDiscussionList(): Observable<DiscussionList[]> | Observable<never> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<DiscussionList[]>('api/discussion-list/data.json');
  }
}
```

The **DataListComponent** class looks like this, and is where I'm having trouble:

```
discussionList$: Observable<DiscussionList>;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    const result = this.route.data.pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('tap data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
    ).subscribe(data => console.log('data ' + JSON.stringify(data)));
  }
```

This produces the following console output, which to me suggests the data is not being received by my component:

```
tap data: {"discussionList$":{"_isScalar":false}}
data {"discussionList$":{"_isScalar":false}}
```

The questions I have are:

1. When should I be using a generic type of DiscussionList versus DiscussionList[]
2. How do I get the discussionList data returned from the **DiscussionListResolverService** into my component?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this in your resolver:

```
return this.discussionListService.getDiscussionList().pipe(
   tap( discussionList => {
     console.log('DiscussionListResolverService returning discusionList:' + discussionList);
   }),
  catchError( err => {
    console.log('DiscussionListResolverService returning EMPTY 1');
    return EMPTY;
  })
);
```

for some reason you're transforming the response into an observable of the response, and telling typescript to ignore the error. you're seeing that log output because you're wrapping it an observable. don't do that.

re using `DiscussionList` vs `DiscussionList[]`, use the first when its one `DiscussionList` object, use the second when it's an array of them.

also, you probably don't want to actually return `EMPTY` in your `catchError` as your UI will just hang in an error case.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to get the data into my componen (as reported by JSON.stringify(), but I still can't figure out how to get the data into the discussionList$ observable within my component.

Comment: Just assign the observable from the route data.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had to make a change: discussionList$ Observable<Data> (instead of DiscussionListModel[]) and then this assignment worked: this.discussionList$ = this.route.data.pipe( map( data => { return data.discussionList$; }) );